# How to create tables from nesteded document and join them using Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I have a dataset that looks as follows

```
data_set = {
    "set_a": {
        "a":1,
        "b":2,
        "c":3 

    },
    "set_b" {
        "x":5,
        "y":6,
        "z":7 
    }
}
```

I want to create separate tables then join them together using KUSTO ( KQL ). How can I do that?

If I want to create a table with `a` and `b` from **set_a** and `x` from **set_b**, How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this could work:

```
print data_set = dynamic({
    "set_a": {
        "a":1,
        "b":2,
        "c":3 
    },
    "set_b": {
        "x":5,
        "y":6,
        "z":7 
    }
})
| project a = data_set.set_a.a, b = data_set.set_a.b, x = data_set.set_b.x
```

| a | b | x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this works. I think `join` will not work since there is no ID / common column right?